# Function To Parse DateTime

Tags: c#, datetime

I have been using this function that I threw together to extract `DateTime` in a `MM/DD/YYYY HH:MM:SS PM` format.  Well the Excel file that I have been parsing is now being altered and the character to split on is now **EITHER** a `+` or `-` whereas before it was **ONLY** a `+`

I attempted to modify my syntax to take an array of characters, but in doing such I now get 2 compile errors:

> Argument 1: cannot convert from 'string[]' to 'char'
>   The best overloaded method match for 'string.IndexOf(char)' has some invalid arguments

How should this be updated in order to accept an array of characters?

2 sample formats that would be passed to the function are:

```
07/22/2016 05:22:00 PM + 00:00
07/22/2016 12:00:00 AM - 04:00
```

And the function is:

```
public static string FormatToUsableDateTime(string DateToConvert)
{
    convertedDateTime = null;
    var charstocheck = new[]
    {
        "+",
        "-"
    };
    int index = DateToConvert.IndexOf(charstocheck);
    convertedDateTime = (index > 0 ? DateToConvert.Substring(0, index) : "");
    return convertedDateTime;
}
```

Comment: Use `DateTime.ParseExact`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because you use `var` in your `charstocheck` variable and do not explicitly state the data type, the compiler assigns it as `string[]`, judging from the way you put the data (by wrapping them with "..." instead of '...')

Besides, `IndexOf` will only check for a *single* character, thus you cannot put an array (be it `string[]` or `char[]`) as its input.

What you could do instead is to check *which* character (+ or -) exists in the `string` and the use that in your `IndexOf`:

```
public static string FormatToUsableDateTime(string DateToConvert)
{
    convertedDateTime = null;
    char chartocheck = DateToConvert.Contains('+') ? '+' : '-';
    int index = DateToConvert.IndexOf(chartocheck);
    convertedDateTime = (index > 0 ? DateToConvert.Substring(0, index) : "");
    return convertedDateTime;
}
```

This fits the situation since you only have two characters to check, *either* + or -. If you have more that two characters to check, you may consider using `IndexOfAny`

**Edit:**

[BACON](https://stackoverflow.com/users/150605/bacon) points out that the pattern to "check-if-exist" and then "use-if-exist" is inefficient most of the time and I agree with that. "check-and-use-if-exist" is often a better solution. The above code can thus be replaced with `IndexOfAny` (as BACON answered) or,

```
int index = DateToConvert.IndexOf('+'); //guess what is more often to come
if (index < 0) //if proven wrong, guess take the other
    index = DateToConvert.IndexOf('-');
```

For more efficient solution.

Comment: Much cleaner than my code and works perfectly, thank you!

Comment: Note that `DateToConvert.Contains` will scan `DateToConvert` character by character until it finds a `'+'` or reaches the end of the string, but does not record where it found the `'+'` if it did.  Then `DateToConvert.IndexOf` will again scan `DateToConvert` character by character until it finds `chartocheck` (which, again, could very well be the `'+'` it already located in the previous line).  This is not a very efficient way to do this, and does not make the code any easier to understand, in my opinion.

Comment: @BACON ah yes, but `IndexOfAny` does that internally too. It scans till any character is found. You may say that these logics *visibly* not looping but *logically* still do

Comment: @Ian We don't know what `IndexOfAny` does internally because it's [implemented externally](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/string.cs,ecb74d23d1c04743), which I take as an indication that it's implemented in a more performant manner than possible in C#. Still, I don't know if it should be recommended to use the "Check if an item exists, then find the index of the item" pattern, especially when a built-in method is available to do, as you say, the same thing. At the least this could be made more efficient by replacing `Contains` with another call to `IndexOf`.

Comment: @BACON: "Check if an item exists, then find the index of the item" pattern, especially when a built-in method is available to do, as you say, the same thing. At the least this could be made more efficient by replacing Contains with another call to IndexOf" I see, I agree with this point and the solution you give. Thanks for pointing it out. I will update my answer. On other note, for all the non-indexed, non-ordered data, (the input `string` in this case) the bottom line is *someone* has to loop, be it `IndexOfAny` (though implemented externally) or `Contains` or `IndexOf`

Comment: @Ian I agree.  My point was not that calling a method magically means there is no looping going on (even under the covers), just that calling `Contains` followed by `IndexOf` guarantees two loops (under the covers) when only one may be necessary (in the case where `'+'` is present in the string).

Answer (score 2):

You can use the [`IndexOfAny` method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/11w09h50.aspx):

```
var charstocheck = new[]
{
    '+',
    '-'
};
int index = DateToConvert.IndexOfAny(charstocheck);
```

Note that `IndexOfAny` accepts an array of `char`, not `string`, so I changed the type of `chartocheck` to `char[]`.

Answer (score 1):

It was because of the .`IndexOf()` method, It has 9 overloaded options but no one will accept a string array as input parameter. you have to do something like this:

```
int index = DateToConvert.IndexOfAny(charstocheck);
```

Which will returns the zero-based index of the first occurrence in this instance of any character in a specified array of Unicode characters. But in this case you should change the `charstocheck` from string array to a character array like this :

```
var charstocheck = new[] { '+', '-' };
```

Comment: simply changing from double quotes to single quotes would change it to a usable input (in this case alter from string to char)?

Comment: you have to use `IndexOfAny` instead for `IndexOf` and change the string array to char array by changing string to char

Comment: The [9 `IndexOf` overloads](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/system.string.indexof.aspx) are defined in the `string` class and are not extension methods, but this is otherwise correct.

Answer (score 1):

If you look at the date i.e. `07/22/2016 05:22:00 PM + 00:00` the issue what I came up is `+ 00:00` that is the space between `+` and `00:00` so If we remove that space we will be able to Parse the Exact date from the string like this

```
string smdt = "07/22/2016 05:22:00 PM + 00:00";
//Find the character. if it is + or -
string chartocheck = smdt.Contains("+") ? "+" : "-";
//Remove the space between the + / - and time
string Correctedsmdt = smdt.Replace(chartocheck + " ", chartocheck);
//This is the string format which is going to parse the Date
string format = "MM/dd/yyyy h:mm:ss tt zzz";
DateTime dt = DateTime.ParseExact(Correctedsmdt, format, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, DateTimeStyles.AssumeUniversal);
```